# calculations on columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

i need to perform a calculation based on this:

(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5) /col6

And when this calculation has been done, i want to perform an orderby based on the result obtained.

Please suggest. I know how to perform the sum like this:

```
SELECT SUM(column1) + SUM(column2) + SUM(columnN) FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (column1+column2+columnN)/column6
FROM mytable
ORDER BY (column1+column2+columnN)/column6
```

Comment: @ppeterka not a lot with oracle... just sometimes

Comment: Just guessed, because you didn't use alias for the order by expression - and I faced that you can't do such in Oracle...

Comment: @ppeterka in mysql you can write it both ways... i usually prefer to use alias because it looks more clean, but this time i wanted to write it this  way :) i think that in oracle you can use an alias in the order by clause, but not in the group by clause

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

```
SELECT ((column1 + column2 + columnN) / column6) as calc 
FROM mytable order by calc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5) /col6 as calculated
FROM your_table
ORDER BY calculated
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
SELECT (column1+column2+columnN) as total,
total/column6 as average
FROM mytable
ORDER BY total
```